# MySql sub select trying to get count of column values

Tags: mysql

2Been spending a few hours on this and it looks ok to me. What am I doing wrong. My database  looks like this.

```
id, type_name
1, 1
2, 3
3, 1
4, 1
5, 2
6, 3
```

My query looks like this .

```
SELECT
DISTINCT(p.`id`) as id,
count (p1.type_name) as L1,
count (p2.type_name) as L2,
count (p3.type_name) as L3
FROM
proxylist AS p

LEFT JOIN (SELECT `id`,`type_name`, count(`type_name`) as L1
WHERE `type_name` = 1) as p1 
ON p1.`id` = p.`id`

LEFT JOIN (SELECT `id`,`type_name`, count(`type_name`) as L1
WHERE `type_name` = 3) as p2 
ON p2.`id` = p.`id`

LEFT JOIN (SELECT `id`,`type_name`, count(`type_name`) as L1
WHERE `type_name` = 3) as p3 
ON p3.`id` = p.`id`

GROUP BY p.`id`
```

I get the error "[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(`type_name`) as L1
WHERE `type_name` = 1) as p1 
ON p1.`id` = p.`id`"

Comment: You are missing with comma in each sub select right after `type_name` also from table is missing too in sub selects

Comment: (although that might not be all that's wrong with this one)

Comment: ya I missed the commas, but its still not working. [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `type_name` = 1) as p1 
ON p1.`id` = p.`id`

Comment: @Cyber read my comment again you are missing with from clause too in sub selects if you want to get count from same table then see Gordon's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.id,
       SUM(p.type_name = 1) as L1,
       SUM(p.type_name = 2) as L2,
       SUM(p.type_name = 3) as L3
FROM proxylist p
GROUP BY p.id;
```

I'm fairly sure that your query will return `1` or `0` for the three calculated values.  The above is reasonable speculation on what you might be trying to do.

Comment: True mysql solution for different types of count from same table

Comment: Damn see I guess I was over complicating the issue again, Thats what I love about this place. sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to look at the issue lol.